# Basic try catch issue

Tags: java, try-catch

```
package mp1practice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Driver 
{    
    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void GrabData() {

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/Catalog.txt"));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }        
}
```

Hello , i have a very basic question regarding try and catch , I am getting an error saying unreported exception. must be caught or declared to be thrown. Any ideas?

SOLVED!!

Comment: Try and catch must be inside a function and not directly in a class. Please update your code.

Comment: Which exception is it complaining about, on which line, and are you catching it?

Comment: @ sebi , i put the line under a function ...solved , THX

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't see any initializer block...

Comment: @Nidhin_toms Your edited code should compile fine.

Comment: @assylias There isn't, but should be. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest change is to place the code in a initialiser block.

```
public class Driver {
    private final List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/Catalog.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

but what would be more useful would be expicit and set a field.

```
public class Driver    {
    private final List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final BufferedReader br;

    public Driver() throws FileNotFoundException {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/Catalog.txt"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put this in your method declaration line.

```
throws FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: a class can't throw an exception.

Comment: I realized this after I wrote it. I meant to say in the main method or whatever method he needed it for. Thanks for catching my error.

Answer (score 1):

First, the try-catch block must be inside of a method. Second, the `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` classes throw an `IOException` as well for file permissions.

So:

```
public void methodName() {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/Catalog.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Driver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something for IO exception here.
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could add `throws Exception` to your method declaration for any other exceptions that could be thrown by the code.

Comment: nothing throws an IOException (apart from the FileNotFoundException) in that code.

Answer (score 1):

With try/catch you can only catch what is actually thrown inside the method your "are trying". So if the exception you want to catch is not defined to be thrown inside the method then you experience the error described above.